# RxJS Filtering and selecting/deselecting list of checkbox

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have a list of checkboxes, and I need to be able to select them ( check them) and I should also be able to filter them and check them while they are filtered. I am able to select the item, filter the item, but as soon as I filter them and then check any value it unchecks the previously selected value. I know the reason why it unchecks because every time user checks/unchecks the value I start with the original checkbox value set. So when I check/uncheck a value in filtered set, it starts again with default set where checkbox value is set to false.

Any suggestions on how to make it work? That is works seamlessly with filtering and checking/unchecking the values.

It looks like a really simple issue but i am stuck with it from past few days. Replicated the issue here. Please take a look. Any suggestions are appreciated .

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmyxtd

```
variables = [
{
"label": "Phone",
"value": "phone",
checked: false
},
{
"label": "Machine Id",
"value": "machine_id",
checked: false
},
{
"label": "Address",
"value": "address",
checked: false
},
{
 "label": "Store",
 "value": "store",
 checked: false
},
{
 "label": "Email",
 "value": "email",
 checked: false
},
{
  "label": "Name",
  "value": "name",
  checked: false
 },
{
  "label": "Credit Card",
  "value": "credit_Card",
  checked: false
 },
  {
   "label": "Bank Account",
  "value": "bank_account",
  checked: false
 }
]
variables$ = of(this.variables).pipe(shareReplay(1),delay(1000));

filteredFlexibleVariables$ = combineLatest(this.variables$, this.filterBy$).pipe(
  map(([variables, filterBy]) => {
    return variables.filter((item) => item.value.indexOf(filterBy) !== -1);
  })
);

toggleStateSelectedVariables$ = combineLatest(
  this.variables$,
  this.toggleFlexibleVariableBy$
).pipe(
   map(([availableVariables, clickedVariable]) => {
    const clickedVariableValues = clickedVariable.map((item) => item.value);
    if (clickedVariable.length) {
     // If condition just to save availableVariables iteration for no reason if there is no clicked variables
      return availableVariables.map((variable) => {
       const checked = clickedVariableValues.indexOf(variable.value) !== -1;
       return {
        ...variable,
        checked
       };
     });
    }
    return availableVariables;
  }),
);

flexibleVariables$ = merge(
   this.filteredFlexibleVariables$,
   this.toggleStateSelectedVariables$
 );
```

Comment: I don't have time right now but I'll try to help you out in the next few days

Comment: @maxime1992 - If you could take a look, that will be highly appreciated

Comment: Took me a bit more time than planned with holidays but I've provided a detailed answer :)

Comment: @maxime1992 - very thorough and detailed answer with a diff approach that I really like and it gives me some more ideas that I can use. Thank you and Happy holidays :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a different approach. As you're trying to **edit** a group of values, this makes me think that using a **form** would be a good idea.

I'm one of the authors of [ngx-sub-form](https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form) and I'll explain the approach I would take using this library to (hopefully?) simplify the workflow and encapsulate the edition of the data then just be warned whenever the form value changes.

Before we start, here's a stackblitz you can play with to see my solution:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nhnmcm

---

First, I'd like to point out that the filter should not be tight to the data themselves. It should just show or hide data in the **view** based on the filter. For that, we can use a pipe:

**filter-item.pipe.ts**

```
@Pipe({
  name: "filterItem"
})
export class FilterItemPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(item: Item, searchFilter: string): Item {
    return item.value.includes(searchFilter);
  }
}
```

And before I forget, here's what an "Item" looks like:

```
export interface Item {
  label: string;
  value: string;
  checked: boolean;
}
```

Now, within our main component we don't want to be aware of how the data are being displayed nor visualized. The only thing which matters is:

- Where do we get our data from?
- When do we update them?

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  public items$: Observable<Item[]> = this.itemsService.items$;
  public search: string = "";

  constructor(private itemsService: ItemsService) {}

  public itemsUpdated(items) {
    this.itemsService.updateItems(items);
  }
}
```

Then, from the view of the main component, we should have 2 components:

- One to tell us what's the value of the filter
- One to display the list of items and tell us when it's been updated

**app.component.html**

```
<app-items-filter (search)="search = $event"></app-items-filter>

<app-items-form
  [items]="items$ | async"
  (itemsUpdated)="itemsUpdated($event)"
  [searchFilter]="search"
></app-items-form>
```

So far, it doesn't look too bad, does it?

But how should we build the `app-items-form` which seems to be holding all the magic?

**items-form.component.ts**

```
interface ItemsForm {
  items: Item[];
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-items-form",
  templateUrl: "./items-form.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./items-form.component.css"]
})
export class ItemsFormComponent extends NgxAutomaticRootFormComponent<
  Item[],
  ItemsForm
> {
  @DataInput()
  @Input("items")
  public dataInput: Item | null | undefined;

  @Output("itemsUpdated")
  public dataOutput: EventEmitter<Item> = new EventEmitter();

  @Input()
  searchFilter: string;

  protected getFormControls(): Controls<ItemsForm> {
    return {
      items: new FormArray([])
    };
  }

  protected transformToFormGroup(obj: Item[]): ItemsForm {
    return {
      items: obj
    };
  }

  public getDefaultValues(): Partial<ItemsForm> {
    return {
      items: []
    };
  }

  protected transformFromFormGroup(formValue: ItemsForm): Item[] | null {
    return formValue.items;
  }
}
```

It may look like a lot is going on there if you haven't discovered `ngx-sub-form` yet. So let me walk you through it.

We use a top level class called `NgxAutomaticRootFormComponent`. That class will ask us to implement the form which is going to hold our data and will automagically bind the form to our input and give us the updated value as an output every time the form is being updated.

It might be slightly easier but as it's an array we need to **wrap** the array into an object as ngx-sub-form only wants to deal with a **FormGroup** internally. But that `formGroup` can contain a `FormArray` (which is what we just did there).

Now, let's take a look to the view:

**items-form.component.html**

```
<ng-container [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <ng-container [formArrayName]="formControlNames.items">
        <app-item-ctrl [hidden]="!(itemCtrl.value | filterItem:searchFilter)"
            *ngFor="let itemCtrl of formGroupControls.items.controls" [formControl]="itemCtrl">
        </app-item-ctrl>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Few important things to notice:
- `ngx-sub-form` gives us access to a `formGroup` property that we can use directly without having to declare it ourselves
- as we're holding a list of values, we use the `formArrayName` directive to work with the `FormArray`
- we use the `hidden` directive provided natively by Angular to hide the controls which are not included by our filter
- last, we delegate the display/edit of the `item` to a sub component called `app-item-ctrl`

This is the "magic" part of `ngx-sub-form`. It's really easy to break down a form into sub form and also at the top level abstract how it's been displayed/edited.

Final part, let's take a look into the sub component:

**item-ctrl.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-item-ctrl",
  templateUrl: "./item-ctrl.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./item-ctrl.component.css"],
  providers: subformComponentProviders(ItemCtrlComponent)
})
export class ItemCtrlComponent extends NgxSubFormComponent<Item> {
  protected getFormControls(): Controls<Item> {
    return {
      label: new FormControl(),
      value: new FormControl(),
      checked: new FormControl()
    };
  }
}
```

Things to notice:

- `providers: subformComponentProviders(ItemCtrlComponent)`: behind the scenes, `ngx-sub-form` is a simple wrapper to deal with a [`ControlValueAccessor`](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/) in an easier way and with a lot less boilerplate. Hence, we need to register the DI tokens required by a `ControlValueAccessor` through that simple function where you just pass the class of the current component
- `getFormControls` this is the method where we have to pass an object that'll be used to create our internal `formGroup`

And the corresponding view:

**item-ctrl.component.html**

```
<div [formGroup]="formGroup">
    {{ formGroupValues.label }}

    <input type="checkbox" [formControl]="formGroupControls.checked" />
</div>
```

**Conclusion:**

When you need to **edit** data, I'd recommend using a form. Whether you use `ngx-sub-form` or decide to use forms directly is up to you.

If I'm explaining how to use ngx-sub-form though, it's because we've invested quite a lot of time at work to come up with that library as we do manage a lot of forms and we needed to abstract the complexity somehow. It has greatly simplified our workflow and I believe the solution above is quite verbose (by the number of components used) but really simple too as we haven't had to deal with streams for ex. (Even though I do love streams but I don't think that in that case it's the best approach).

Hope it helps and here's the final stackblitz I've made: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nhnmcm

Answer (score 0):

Wow.. so after a lot of brainstorming and frustrating moments I was able to solve this. I was thinking it in a different way. What I ended up doing was to create a stream of toggled Values (select/unselect checkboxes) and then filter on those toggled values.

So in summary -

```
Stream 1 - Merged stream of original set of variables & clicked variable. Use scan operator to get the updated stream at any point

Stream 2 - Consume the above stream and apply filter on the above stream.

toggleStateSelectedVariables$ = merge(this.variables$, this.toggleFlexibleVariableBy$).pipe(
throttleTime(100),
scan((availableVariables: NzCheckBoxOptionInterface[], clickedVariableValue: NzCheckBoxOptionInterface) => {
  return availableVariables.map((variable) => {
    // If its clicked, toggle it. If its selected, make it unselected. If unselected, select it
    const checked = variable.value === clickedVariableValue.value ? !variable.checked : variable.checked;
    return {
      ...variable,
      checked
    };

  });
}),

);

flexibleVariables$ = combineLatest(this.toggleStateSelectedVariables$, this.filterBy$).pipe(
   map(([variables, filterBy]) => variables.filter((item) => item.value.indexOf(filterBy) !== -1);
  ));
```

Implementation available here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ymft6o

Hope this helps someone. If anyone has any better solutions, please chime in

Happy Learning,

Vatsal